# turning string into a number

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to calculate the price total of the below html code and add the result to the dom throuh the JS code further below:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
<span class="p-name">IronBubble-head</span>
<span id="price-number">$25</span>
<label id="qty" for="qty">QTY</label><input type="number" value="1">
<span id="total">0</span>
<button class="btn btn-delete" type="button">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>
```

and this javascript code:

```
function getTotalPrice(e) {
var Price = document.getElementById('price-number').value;
var Quantity = document.getElementById('qty').value;
var Total = document.getElementById('total');
total.innerHTML = Price * Quantity;
}
```

Although the result I get is always NaN.
where is the mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to parse the string as a number using parseInt. You'll need to remove the dollar sign first though, or you'll get an error. I'd post an answer, but my phones at 4%.

Comment: Hey @Carcigenicate I have tried to follow your suggestion but I still see a NaN:  this is the HTML amended without the $ sign:

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
<span class="p-name">IronBubble-head</span>
<span id="price-number">25</span>
<label id="qty" for="qty">QTY</label><input type="number" value="1">
<span id="total">0</span>
<button class="btn btn-delete" type="button">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>

Comment: and here the JS:

and here the JS

function getTotalPrice(e) {
  var Price = parseInt(document.getElementById('price-number'));
  var Quantity = document.getElementById('qty').value;
  var Total = document.getElementById('total');
  total.innerHTML = Price * Quantity;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your #price-number element has $ character, that you cant make math operation, so you need clean first.

So you could use a `.replace` to remove $ character:

```
Price = Price.replace(/\$/, '');
```

And instead of use `.value` you may use `.innerHTML`

```
var Price = document.getElementById('price-number').value;
```

Another thing is to put the `id="qty"` in input element, cause the value is in there.

Like that:

```js
function getTotalPrice() {
  var Price = document.getElementById('price-number').innerHTML;
  Price = Price.replace(/\$/, '');
  var Quantity = document.getElementById('qty').value;
  var Total = document.getElementById('total');
  total.innerHTML = Price * Quantity;
}

getTotalPrice();
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
    <span class="p-name">IronBubble-head</span>
    <span id="price-number">$25</span>
    <label for="qty">QTY</label><input id="qty" type="number" value="1">
    <span id="total">0</span>
    
    <button class="btn btn-calc" type="button" onclick="getTotalPrice()">Calc</button>
    <button class="btn btn-delete" type="button">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a pretty thin answer. You should explain what changes you've made and their significance.

Comment: Great thanks so much @PhelipeRocha I saw that the mistake was in putting the ID on the label rather than the input of the quantity html.
May I ask you why you decided to use the .innerHTML at the end of the Price variable in the JS? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because `#price-number` is a spam element, and the value is inside the span.. So, to get this it's needed to use `.innerHTML` and `.value` is to get values from inputs, selects and that kind of elements

Answer (score 0):

Your code stores "$25" as a string in the variable Price. You need to remove the dollar sign and parse the "25" string as an integer. For example you could add this line to your code anywhere after your initial assignment of the variable Price:

```
Price = parseInt(Price.slice(1, Price.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need strip out any non-numeric characters from price value

```
var priceValue = parseFloat(Price.textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/, ''), 10)
```

Full Code

```
var Price = document.getElementById('price-number')
var Quantity = document.getElementById('qty')
var Total = document.getElementById('total')

function getTotalPrice() {
  var priceValue = parseFloat(Price.textContent.replace(/[^\d.]/, ''), 10)
  var quantityValue = parseFloat(Quantity.value, 10) || 0
  var totalValue = priceValue * quantityValue

  return totalValue
}

Quantity.addEventListener('input', function() {
    total.innerHTML = getTotalPrice()
})
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mkpyvqfh/6/**